# Are there any PDF viewing software that allows split view?

Tags: 16.04, pdf, evince, foxitreader

I'm on 16.04 and would like to view two different sections of the same PDF in the same window. I know it is possible to open several instances of PDF viewer but that's rather annoying.

I've tried Foxit, Evince, Okular... and several others. It seems that none of them seem to offer this feature in Ubuntu. A bit of googling suggests Konqueror but I wasn't able to get it to work either...

Comment: I was expecting there must be a software that allows you to view a pdf with a dividing bar that allows you to resize the relative proportions of the split view just by dragging it up and down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies, as you have suspected, in Konqueror which has an option under:

```
Window --> Split View Left/Right
Window --> Split View Top/Bottom
```

I attach a screenshot demonstrating this on my own system:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But how do you open a pdf in konqueror in the first place? I tried tweaking ConfigureKonqueror-FileManagement-FileAssociations-pdf-General/Embedding so many times and open get a blank window when opening pdfs.

Comment: ok embedding with okular works on one computer but not another...

Comment: @matohak I actually opened Konqueror and then used File -- Open...